# Putting two tables side by side (one table with subtables)

Tags: tables, subfloats, minipage

I want to put two tables side by side. Table 1 has two subtables in it. Each table itself is built using the `\begin{tabular}` environment. A sample of the table is here:

[image]

How to do it?

Comment: Use two `minipage`s, e.g. as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119152/two-table-environments-side-by-side?rq=1

Comment: Put each of Table 1 and Table 2 in a minipage of its own (top-aligned).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \subfloat[Type 1]%
      {\begin{tabular}{|c|}
         \hline
         \rule{2cm}{1cm} \\
         \hline
       \end{tabular}
      }

    \subfloat[Type 2]%
      {\begin{tabular}{|c|}
         \hline
         \rule{2cm}{1cm} \\
         \hline
       \end{tabular}
      }
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
      \hline
      \rule{2cm}{1cm} \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```